# Hi. I have a dataframe like below, where I would like to calculate the cotton production for each row, based on percentage in some other columns

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I am relatively new to Python and I am facing a conditional calculation issue.
I have the following table and I would create a new column:

| RM1 | RM2 | RM3 | RM1% | RM2% | RM3% | Prod(kg/h) | New Column Cotton Prod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cotton | Cotton | NaN | 50 | 50 | NaN | 20 | 20 |
| Waste | Cotton | Waste | 10 | 50 | 40 | 20 | 10 |
| Other | NaN | Cotton | 50 | NaN | 100 | 20 | 20 |

The Problem is that Cotton is not the only raw material within RM1, RM2, RM3 and the percentage of each raw material is given by RM1%, RM2%, RM3%. I would like to calculate only the rows which contain the string "Cotton". Can someone help me with this?

I have something like this:

```
conditions = [
    (RM1 == "Cotton") & (RM2 != Cotton) & (RM3 != Cotton),
    (RM1 == "Cotton") & (RM2 == Cotton) & (RM3 != Cotton)
    ...all combinations
    ]
    
    values = [RM1% * Prod(kg/h)/100,
    RM1% + RM2 (*Prod(kg/H)]
    
    df['New Columns Cotton Prod'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

Comment: Example for the firs row would be: 50% + 50% (*20/100). as these are the two cotton percentages

Comment: For working and manipulating tabular data I recommend the module pandas. Have a look at it and specify where you are stuck :)

Comment: I have sosmething like this: conditions = [
(RM1 == "Cotton") & (RM2 != Cotton) & (RM3 != Cotton),
(RM1 == "Cotton") & (RM2 == Cotton) & (RM3 != Cotton)
...all combinations
]

values = [RM1% * Prod(kg/h)/100,
RM1% + RM2 (*Prod(kg/H)]

df['New Columns Cotton Prod'] = np.select(conditions, values)

Comment: If you have code, it should be [edit]ed into the question as a [mre]

Comment: The title is not a field where you just put in the first line or two of your question -- your title should _summarize your actual specific question_. [Ask]. If this is a `pandas` dataframe, please add the [tag:pandas] tag to your question. It is not clear what you want to do to your dataframe. Do you want `new_column = production * sum(RM1% + RM2% + RM3%)` but only if the RM values `== "Cotton"`? Please show your expected output for the given input

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.